# Hopfield Network?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a question about the formation of weight matrix in Hopfield network:
Why is not considered self-loop (i.e. $w_{ii}=0$)?

Can anyone help me in the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: write down the energy, see how it changes when $w_{i,i}$ (for some $i$) is  changed from zero to some nonzero value. Assume that the values of the nodes are $\pm 1$

Comment: I have assumed a weight matrix 2*2 in which the elements of main diagonal of matrix are 2 and the others are -2.

Comment: I this case the energy becomes $E=-(x_{1}-x_2)^2$ which is negative!

Comment: while with these conditions but considering zeros in the main diagonal of weight matrix I get the Energy becomes $E=x_1*x_2$.

Comment: in this case depends on the sign of $x_1$ and $x_2$!

Comment: Now, how I can decide with these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy of a configuration $S=\{s_i : s_i= \pm1 \}$is given by

$$-E(S) = \sum_{i , j} w_{ij} s_i s_j + \sum_i \theta_i s_i $$

The cuadratic sum can be decomposed in "non-diagonal" and "diagonal" terms:  $$\sum_{i , j} w_{ij} s_i s_j = \sum_{i \ne j} w_{ij} s_i s_j + \sum_{i } w_{ii} \, s_i^2 = \sum_{i \ne j} w_{ij} s_i s_j + \sum_{i } w_{ii}$$

The last equality is a consequence of $s_i^2 = 1$. Then, we see that if we modify the diagonal terms $w_{ii}$, the energy is modified by a constant amount (i.e, a value that does not depend on the configuration $s_i$). But we are not interested in the absolute value of the energy, we just want to find the configuration that attains the minimum; hence, modifying $w_{ii}$ has no relevance, hence we choose to set it to zero.

Comment: @ leonbloy: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: But I have yet this problem why $w_{ii}$ is considered zero? Where do we consider the absolute value of the energy as you have mentioned?

Comment: Considering the value of zero for $w_{ii}$ can effect on stability analysis?

Comment: @Royana I have shown why $w_{ii}$ does not matter to locate the minimum. We usually assign it to zero because that's the simpler alternative (both for theoretical analysis and for numerical computation).

Comment: BTW: welcome to MSE, take some minutes to read the FAQ and to understand how the site works. This is not a chat/forum, long threads of comments are not welcomed.